# How to check select list is multiple or not? Select2 JQuery, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have select list. It can be multiple or single select in case of action.

```
<select name="" id="cmb_employee"  class="js-example-basic-multiple" >
</select>
```

In  cmb_employee on change/ I want to determinite select list is multiple or not. 
I tried this but it works for multiple not for single

```
 $("#cmb_employee").on('change', function () {
  var isMulti = document.getElementById('cmb_employee').multiple;
  if(isMulti){
     alert("is multi select");
    }
  else {
    alert("is not");
  }});
```

Note 1: I use Select2

```
 $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({ width: '100%', cushion: 54 });
```

Note 2: To change single to multiple

```
 $("#cmb_employee").select2({
                            multiple: true,
                            placeholder: "Seçin...",
                        });
```

Note 3: To change Multi to single select

```
 $("#cmb_employee").select2({
                                multiple: false,
                                placeholder: "Seçin...",
                            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select2` options to get the current status of multiple.
`$('#cmb_employee').data('select2').options.options.multiple`

```js
$('#cmb_employee').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month',
    multiple:true
});

$("#single").click(function(){
$('#cmb_employee').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month',
    multiple:false
});
})

$("#multiple").click(function(){
$('#cmb_employee').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month',
    multiple:true
});
})

$("#check").click(function(){
console.log("is dropdown is multiple? "+$('#cmb_employee').data('select2').options.options.multiple);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<select id="cmb_employee"  style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>

<button id="single">
Change to single
</button>
<button id="multiple">
Change to multiple
</button>
<button id="check">
Check dropdown is multiple or not
</button>
```